Why do my cabbages droop in the sun?
I recently started to grow some cabbages from seed, however a couple days after transplanting I noticed that whenever in the direct sun, their leaves start to droop and feel limp to the touch. At night they return to strong upright leaves, is this normal?


Normal for small seedlings, yes, but it's not something you want to happen; keep them shaded or out of the sun until they have got bigger with more leaves and are more robust, they're too young and tender to tolerate direct sun at their current size.

Thankyou very much, I've moved them into a shady area and will monitor them.
